# I get a Could not find InAppBrowser plugin in ionic ios app

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a simple Ionic app in which I want to integrate Facebook login, however when I try to sign in, I get the message `Could not find InAppBrowser plugin`.

After searching a bit on the web I found out that it might be because of the plugin name which has changed overtime from `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` to `org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`.

The suggested solution were to edit the ng-cordova.js file to reference the plugin name I was using, but when I went to edit it, it was already referencing both plugin names inside that function :

```
isInAppBrowserInstalled: function(cordovaMetadata) {
                var inAppBrowserNames = ["cordova-plugin-inappbrowser", "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"];

                return inAppBrowserNames.some(function(name) {
                    return cordovaMetadata.hasOwnProperty(name);
                });
            },
```

I tried to `alert(JSON.stringify(cordovaMetadata));` to see what was going on, but it returned an empty object like {}.

Also, if I do `cordova plugin ls`, here is what I get:

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media 1.0.1 "Media"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.7 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: Where exactly do you run this code in the ionic lifecycle?

Comment: It is inside an Angular JS app and it gets fired when I click on a Facebook button : `$cordovaOauth.facebook("FB_APP_ID", ["email"]).then(function(result) {
            // results
            alert(result.access_token);
            console.log(result);
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error);
        });`

Comment: @AndreKreienbring any idea?

Comment: You need to add an entry into your `config.xml`. Make sure to `source=npm`.

Comment: I get the same problem, any Idea?

Comment: I got a response from the github team and it seems to be an error with the last release.  Supposedly they are working on a fix.  https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/809

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, and instead of using:

"cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"

I used:

"cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git"

And it works, i follow the instructions of this link:
https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/issues/57

Good luck